# How to setup multi-project IntelliJ workspace with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Hello I am working on using Gradle to build a few services. I tend to have seperate repositories for each "code package" i.e. library or service.

In IntelliJ, my setup tends to be the following:

```
- IntelliJ Workspace
-- Service A
--- pom.xml
-- Service B
--- pom.xml
-- Library A
--- pom.xml
-- Library B
--- pom.xml
```

Service A & B both depend on Library A & B. This works great, within a single IntelliJ Workspace I can modify Library A and B and startup the services and all is well.

I know you can do composite builds and multi-module builds with Gradle but like I said all the 4 modules above are seperate repositories so this won't work well.

**Will IntelliJ support a similar setup as above with Gradle where it recongizes that Library A & B is the library that Service A & B depend on? Or does everyone do a manual publish to Maven local for this consistently?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your question -
there are 3 separate gradle projects service1, lib1, lib2
service1 depends on lib1 and lib2

what is expected is

1. for local development - where source for all 3 projects locally exists - use the local code build
2. refer to the repository artifacts if local source does not exist

Assuming a simple folder structure like this.

```
app-code
- service1
- lib1
- lib2
```

service1 - settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'service1'

include ':lib1'
project(':lib1').projectDir = new File('../lib1')

include ':lib2'
project(':lib2').projectDir = new File('../lib2')
```

service1 - build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation (project(':lib1').projectDir.exists() ? project(':lib1') : 'com.lib1:lib1:1.0.0')
    implementation (project(':lib2').projectDir.exists() ? project(':lib2') : 'com.lib2:lib2:1.0.0')
}
```

how intellij import looks

[image]