# Gradle dependency substitutions

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to use the dependency substitution feature of Gradle as mentioned in the official documentation here : [Gradle Documentations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html#sub:project_to_module_substitution).

According to the lines stated at the end of the paragraph that during the MultiProject builds inferred by me as the process when we clean and build the project, indicates that when I clean and build the root project instead of building the dependency that is substituted with its downloadable.

Root Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            (.. content committed ..)
    }
}

plugins {
    (.. content committed ..)
}

configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute project(":base-api") because "we use a stable version of base-api" with module("com.xyz:base-api:0.0.1")
        }
}
   
allprojects {
    
    repositories {
        mavenLocal() 
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    
    group = 'com.xyz'

        (.. content committed ..)

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":base-api")
    }
    
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}

subprojects {
   
    (.. Tasks and blocks related to publishing ..)
}
```

Root Project setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'abc'

include ':base-api'
(.. other subprojects ..)
```

With the above configuration when I execute the clean and build on the root project it does still try to build the local project. So all I wanted to know is

1. Am I missing something here on how it is done properly?
2. Also what is the suggested right way using working with multi projects builds when in a scenario in which a developer has to work on just one of the submodules and the developer does not spend any time to build something that is of no pertinence to the developer.

Edit: Also forgot to mention that I did try to add the configuration.all{} block to all projects as well but it served no purpose.

Edit2: Readded a key dependency that was removed by mistake

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your config has project `abc` & sub project `base-api`, there is no dependency b/w them because you are missing dependencies in abc

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":base-api")        
}
```

note - the build will still do sub-project `base-api` build, but won't use it in the build of `abc`

Comment: Ya just noticed after ur answer that I removed the essential dependency of ":base-api" as well added that back in place

Comment: Also could u answer my second question as well .....going by ur note, it then seems very time ineffecient to build the entire root along with all subprojects when i already have successful build of the other ones in the first place.

Comment: The answer is subjective - the relations / dependencies of project / sub project are defined 'as a whole' and not for individual developer speed. But based on your scenario -  you can choose an approach like https://stackoverflow.com/a/62873054/5845802

Comment: Well this would always use the local code when I available, while what I required is somewhat the other way round.........I mean I want to always use the artifacts as those are stable and would save build time unless they aren't available in the repository.